# http.createServer() is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-proxy

I am new to node.js http-proxy. I tried using it, but it gives me error : Uncaught TypeError: http.createServer is not a function. I tried to search it online but nothing solved my problem. I also have installed npm http-proxy.
Here is the code:

```
var http = require('http');
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: 'http://www.google.com' }, function(err) {
        if(err)
            console.error(err);
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: works for me, I don't get any error message...

Comment: What version of node.js do you use? This could be a problem that you are running a old verison. Use `node --version`

Comment: make sure those modules you are requiring are installed in your node modules

Comment: @NewbeeDev `http` is part of the "standard library" of Node and doesn't require an additional installation.

Comment: my node version is v0.12.5